# Problema con el observable route.queryParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

Buenas, lo que intento hacer es pasar 2 valores dentro de un array desde un componente hacia otro, y recibirlos en la función `ngOnInit()` del componente hijo.

La manera en la que los envío desde el **componente1** es la siguiente:

**HTML**

```
<button class="boton" type="button" (click)="navegar()"></button>
```

**TS**

```
navegar = function () {
   let parametros: any[] = [];
   parametros.push(this.var1);
   parametros.push(this.var2)
   this.router.navigate(['/componente2'], { queryParams: { array: parametros} });
}
```

Y los recibo así:

**TS**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.route.queryParams
     .subscribe(params => {
       if (params !== {} && params.array[0] === "true") {
         this.varAux = params.array[1];
       }
     })
}
```

---

Lo que sucede es que cuando accedo al **componente2** sin haber navegado desde el **componente1**, sino que desde otro lado de la aplicación y se ejecuta `ngOnInit()`, recibo `params = {}`.

> No encuentro la forma de validar que ese objeto sea vacío para así,
>   que no entre a la condición if else.

¿Desde que propiedad del DOM de queryParams puedo hacer una validación para que directamente no se subscriba si es que no llegan parámetros?

Answer (score 0):

El problema de tu comparación es que estás creando un objeto y luego preguntando si es el mismo que el recibido, lo que siempre te va a devolver false.

```js
let a={};
let b={};
console.log(a==b)
```

Si quieres comprobar si existe un atributo, en este caso array, simplemente hazlo así:

```js
let p= {
  array: ['test',true]
}

function test(p) {
  if (p && p.array) {
    console.log(p.array[0]);
  } else {
    console.log('No encontrado');
  }
}

test(p);
test({})
```

Comment: Ya lo he probado, y sigue validandose true a pesar de que viene vacío.

Comment: Probé lo siguiente, y resumo mi consulta así. `let test = {}; test=={}?true:false`, ¿Por qué siempre retorna false?

Comment: Porque estás comparando dos instancias distintas de la clase objeto

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice fue parsear a string el response del subscribe y validar sobre su longitud

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams
    .subscribe((params: any) => {
      let aux: string = JSON.stringify(params)
      if (aux.length > 2 && params.array[0] === "true") {
        this.varAux = params.array[1];
      }
   })
}
```

Sigue abierta a una solución para validar previo a subscribirme al queryParams, para saber si hay una propiedad del observable que me indique si recibo parametros o no desde la navegación